# How to find the type of Matrix

Tags: matrices

I was trying to solve my higher secondary question paper but got stuck in below question:

A square matrix A = a[ij]nxn is defined aij =   1 for i = j and 0 for i ≠ j then A is what type of matrix - zero, unit, upper triangular or lower triangular one.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where did you get stuck?

Comment: Well not able to understand the question in detail

Comment: In situations  like this, write out the matrix explicitly in the $1\times 1$ or $2\times2$ case, and see if the problem seems simpler.  If so, you are making progress, and go to $3\times3$.

Comment: Well I can do that but not able to understand the remaining part -  aij = 1 for i = j and 0 for i ≠ j

Comment: So what is $A$ in the $2\times2$ case?  It is a square array of 4 numbers; what are they?

Comment: It is a square matrix which has 2 cols and 2 rows

Comment: What are its 4 entries?

Comment: I am not sure as it is not provided in the question or asking for an example

Comment: OK got it - a11, a22 ect are all 1 and others are 0

Comment: OK!  Way to go!  Is this the zero matrix?  Do you recall the definition of the other 3 types of matrices?

Comment: No it is a unit matrix - no I do not recall the other type of matrices